# C++ SQLite query works just once. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, sqlite, select

I have a function witch contains this code, when I call this function in first time, it will give the results, but after that every time I call it no result returns. I need to fix this.

```
char query[150];
sprintf(query, "SELECT building, inner, level, position, village FROM Builds WHERE village=%d AND inner=%d", villageId, side);
std::string path=FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath() + "data.db3";
sqlite3 *pDB;
int result = sqlite3_open(path.c_str(), &pDB);

sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;
sqlite3_prepare(pDB, query, -1, &selectStmt, NULL);

std::list<Build> buildings;
// get data
while (1) {
    int s;
    s = sqlite3_step(selectStmt);
    if (s == SQLITE_ROW) {
        Build building;
        building.building = sqlite3_column_int(selectStmt, 0);
        building.inner = sqlite3_column_int(selectStmt, 1);
        building.level = sqlite3_column_int(selectStmt, 2);
        building.position = sqlite3_column_int(selectStmt, 3);
        building.village = sqlite3_column_int(selectStmt, 4);
        buildings.push_back(building);
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
// clode database
sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt);
sqlite3_close(pDB);

// return data
return buildings;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the errors that you get?

Comment: To get the error code, change `sqlite3_prepare` to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. The V1 version of that function only returns a generic code on error, and is deprecated anyway. [Docs here](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html).

Comment: There is no error here. the problem is I can not execute the same query again. I get no rows after the first time. Is there any way to set the cursor up to the start 'sort of speak'.

Comment: same thing with sqlite3_prepare_v2.

Comment: How can you assert that there is no error when you never check for errors?

Comment: I did some debugging, in the first round no error accour, but in the second call I get this:

Comment: cocos2d: result = 21
cocos2d: error = unable to open database file

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by reducing closing and reopening the database. I also used

```
sqlite3_open_v2(path.c_str(), pDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
```

for opening and

```
sqlite3_open_v2(path.c_str(), pDB, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
```

in the beginning of the execution